# What does what'sis'sit stand for?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Here is a line in the TV series *Central Park* s1 e1 at 06:40.

> So, you're probably thinking, "Who is Bitsy What'sis'sit?"

What does *What'sis'sit* stand for?

Answer (score 1):

**Whatsis** – a thing or object whose name one does not know or cannot recall.
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/whatsis

Comment: Thanks. What does what'sis'sit relate to whatsis?

Comment: @FrankMi The line in the TV show is a mispronunciation, or an exaggeration of the word "whatsis", used to substitute the person's forgotten last name:   *"Who is Bitsy Whatsername?" "Whatserface"*

Comment: I 've never heard 'whatsis' - as a BrE speaker I would say 'whatsit'. This seems to be a combination of the two.